# How to define u to solve greens equation

Tags: fft, ifft

this is doing my nut in. I need to define u in the following equation (there is a lot more to it but this is a sample):

$$G(x,x',z,z') = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left(-ju(x'-x)\right)exp(-jk|z-z'|) \,du$$

I know that there is no perfect solution, so i need to create a numerical approximation using the inverse fourier transform in python to take this from the frequency domain into the the spatial domain.

The spatial coordinates are x 0:190, y 0:1909, how do it define u? I know that simplistically `u` is considered to be -1/(x/2) to +1/(x/2) but it cannot be that simple, can it?

Ordinarily the fourier transforms goes from f(x,y) to F(u,v), however in this case the fourier transform is from f(x,z) to F(u,z). I need to define u in the fourier domain, from which i can perform a discrete IFFT which will give me the greens function in the spatial domain, the question is how to define `u` (is it just -1/2x to 1/2x??) or is does it need to be defined as a function (similar to using fourier to solve the heat equation), if so what sort of function?

cheers,

chas

Comment: Green function has many different forms. I think $u$ should be related to frequency, it seems to be "wave vector" but I'm not sure. Please give more information about what you are doing. And I don't see $z$ and $z'$ in the RHS.

Comment: I have converted your image to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  (edit may be pending). Please check I have done so correctly and master using MathJax in the future.

Comment: @ZR Han, thanks, I have abbrievated the formula (there is another exp(-jk|z-z'|) multiplication after this).

Comment: This is being used to solve the Born scattering equation, but i seem to have got into a pickle by not being able to define u properly.

Comment: Please edit your question. And what’s the physical meaning of u?